# iOS: First screen display image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

For my phone application, I would like to display an Image in the first screen during 3 secondes and to switch to a main menu without user action.

**How can I perform the tempo and switching automatically views ?**

Thank you.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is known as a splash screen, 
See [App Launch (Default) Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) 
Or refer to this [guide](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/)

Comment: But you can't control the time of the launch image being shown

Comment: Yes with this method you can't it will display for roughly 1 second but i referenced the guide as it is simple to follow

Comment: You can call `sleep(3)` in `applicationDidFinishLauching`, in order to wait for 3 seconds before show the main view

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadMainView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

with the `loadMainView` method you should begin to setup your usual view

Answer (score 0):

I usually do that by creating a view controller that has a UIImageView with the launch image in its view.

## Using a modal

You can present it as a modal view controller on top of your rootViewController in this way.
In the AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you present the modal by calling

```
// rootViewController is the view controller attached to the UIWindow
[rootViewController presentViewController:imageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Inside the imageViewController you can do this:

```
- (void)dismiss {
    // You can animate it or not, depending on your needs
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}

- (void)viewDidApper {
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:AMOUNT_OF_TIME];
}
```

## As the first controller of a UINavigationController stack

A similar way that doesn't involve modals is to push this view controller in your UINavigationController (if you use it)

In the AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you have to set the first controller of the navigation controller with something like this

```
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Inside the imageViewController you can do this:

```
- (void)dismiss {
    // Here you should init your nextViewController, the real "home" of the app
    ....

    // Then you can present it. You can animate it or not, depending on your needs.
    // I prefer to replace the whole stack, since user shouldn't go back to the image screen.  
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[nextViewController] animated:YES];    
}

- (void)viewDidApper {
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:AMOUNT_OF_TIME];
}
```